# How do I fix the error "subscript out of range" in QBASIC?

Tags: subscript, qbasic, qb64

I'm trying to create a code that generates random numbers within the range 10-30 but making sure that no number is repeated. It shows "subscript out of range" on `NumArray(Count) = Count` when I run the code.

```
'Make an array of completely sorted numbers
FOR Count = 10 TO 30
    NumArray(Count) = Count  
NEXT Count  
RANDOMIZE TIMER  
FOR Count = 10 TO 30
    Number = (RND * (31 - Count)) + 10
    PRINT #1, NumArray(Number)
    FOR Counter = Number TO 30 - Count
        NumArray(Counter) = NumArray(Counter + 1)
    NEXT Counter 
NEXT Count
```

This isn't actually my code. Copied and pasted for my assignment.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're missing some `DIM` statements.

Variables containing numbers have type `SINGLE` by default, so you might see something like `FOR Counter = 18.726493 TO 20` because the `RND` function returns a number between 0 and 1, excluding 1, meaning you will be trying to use `NumArray(18.726493)` which will not work.

Arrays that are not explicitly declared can only have 11 items with an index from 0 to 10, but the range 10-30 requires you to store 21 items (`30 - 10 + 1 = 21`).  You can also specify a custom upper and lower bound if it will make your code easier for you to understand.  Add these lines before the first line in your code shown above:

```
DIM Number AS INTEGER
DIM NumArray(10 TO 30) AS INTEGER
```

This will ensure `Number` only contains integers (any fractional values are rounded to the nearest integer), and `NumArray` will work from `NumArray(10)` to `NumArray(30)`, but you can't use `NumArray(9)`, `NumArray(8)`, `NumArray(31)`, etc.  The index must be in the range 10-30.

I think that should fix your code, but I don't know for certain since I don't fully understand how it is supposed to work.  At the very least, it will fix the type and subscript problems in your code.

Comment: Nitpick: Not explicitly declared arrays have 11 elements with index values 0 to 10.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the array:

```
'Make an array of completely sorted numbers
DIM NumArray(30) AS INTEGER
FOR Count = 10 TO 30
    NumArray(Count) = Count  
NEXT Count  
RANDOMIZE TIMER  
FOR Count = 10 TO 30
    Number = (RND * (31 - Count)) + 10
    PRINT #1, NumArray(Number)
    FOR Counter = Number TO 30 - Count
        NumArray(Counter) = NumArray(Counter + 1)
    NEXT Counter 
NEXT Count
```